# HC06 not able to connect to Samsung Note4 Bluetooth even it is paired

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, serial-port, android-bluetooth, arduino-uno

I am using Arduino UNO R3 to connect a HC06 bluetooth module referring below article, i am using MAC Book

http://tronixlabs.com/news/tutorial-using-hc06-bluetooth-to-serial-wireless-uart-adaptors-with-arduino/

I am able to connect to HC06 using serial monitor of Arduino IDE where HC06 LED get static.

But I am unable to connect to Note 4 Bluetooth it get paired using password 1234 but never able to connect and show up on Terminal on my android. What is wrong?

LED keep blinking after pair, please guide

Added sketch URL:https://codebender.cc/sketch:238653

Comment: Can you show us your Arduino sketch?

Comment: Yes you can see at this link https://codebender.cc/sketch:238653

Comment: Thanks. The code looks fine to me. Another guess that I have: The HC06 is a slave module. A BT-slave can only be connected to one BT-Master at a time. Is your HC06 probably connected to something else, while you are trying to connect to it with your Android smartphone? Unrelated to your problem, but nevertheless an important hint: You probably should connect the RX-PIN of the BT-module with a voltage devider! [See Screenshot of circuit](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lwMAs.jpg) If you don't do this, it might damage your module in the long term. (The levels there are only 3,3V, not 5V!)

Comment: Thanks Michael, let me check by doing this.